# Raycast rotate help need in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have this code which lets an object rotate on Y axis. But I want to rotate the object on Z axis only. I tried to change the **hPlane** value, but no luck.
How can I do this?
Thanks

```
private Ray ray;
private Quaternion target;
private float speed = 1000.0f;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetMouseButton (0)) {
        ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);

        Plane hPlane = new Plane(Vector3.up, Vector3.zero);
        float distance = 0; 
        if(hPlane.Raycast(ray, out distance)){

            Vector3 targetPoint = ray.GetPoint(distance);
            targetPoint += transform.position;

            Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(targetPoint - transform.position);
            float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;

            transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, targetRotation,step);
           }       
        }
    }
```

Update:

My Goal is to rotate a bar (cube mesh) on Z axis smoothly using mouse click . The rotation will occur only when (this part I could not do) the mouse touch the corners of the bar.

I have already done the Z axis rotation with this code but the rotation very low (even for speed =1000.0f) and it rotates clockwise I suppose. But I want to move the bar in both direction and the movement will be smooth and faster like Quaternion.RotateTowards

Thanks

```
private Ray ray;
private RaycastHit hit;
private Quaternion target;
private float speed = 1000.0f;


// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetMouseButton (0)) {
        ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
        if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)){
            //transform.position = new Vector3(hit.point.x, hit.point.y, 0);
            target = Quaternion.Euler(0.0f,0.0f, hit.point.z * speed);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, target, Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }

}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qIcs.jpg

Comment: Actually, you can't rotate your object around Z axis if you use `Quaternion.LookRotation(...)` because this function return a quaternion that will orient the forward (so the Z axis) of the object in the indicated direction. Explain what is the goal of your code.

Comment: I have edited my question with explaination.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to change the orientation of the object axis. For a better use of the Quaternion functions, edit your bar in order to have local Y has rotation axis and local Z as look direction.

Then use this code :

```
if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
{
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit hit;
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
    {
        Vector3 distance = hit.point - transform.position;
        distance.y = 0;
        Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(distance);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, targetRotation, Time.deltaTime * speed);
    }
}
```

Your bar will only rotate around Y axis.